# Summing up and Dirichlet's principle.

Tags: combinatorics

We are given $n$ integers. Using Dirichlet principle to prove that among them there is a number divisible by $n$ or there are numbers whose sum is divisible by $n$.
I  think that we should consider every number modulo n and next consider their sum. Please give me a hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Suppose we have $n$ numbers $a_k, k =1 ,2, \cdots, n$, then consider $$b_m = \sum_{k=1}^m a_k, m = 1, 2, \cdots, n$$

What happens if none of $b_m$ is divisible by $n$? What is the set of their remainders?